# Concatenate DataFrame where the values are the same and drop values where values are different

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to merge two DataFrame columns `(A & B)` where column values are the same while dropping the remainder values (remainder values being those values where column values are not the same).

I have (DataFrame 1):

```
A | B
-----
a | a
b | b
c | a
```

I need (DataFrame 2):

```
A 
-
a 
b
```

Where column `A` in `DataFrame 2` is columns `(A & B)` post-merger.

My code returns `c values` (c values - from the example above) and looks like:

```
df_y = pd.DataFrame([y_testset]).transpose()
df_pT = pd.DataFrame([predTree]).transpose()
df_pT.rename(columns = {0: 'Drug'}, inplace = True)

df_y.reset_index(inplace = True)
df_y.drop('index',axis = 1, inplace = True)

new_df = pd.concat([df_pT, df_y], axis = 1, join ='inner', keys = ['Drug'])
new_df
```

Comment: `df = df[df['A'] == df['B']].drop('B', axis=1)` ??

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df[df["A"].isin(df["B"])]
df = df.drop(['B'], axis=1)
df = df.set_index('A')
df
```

Output:

```
A
_
a
b
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, @AtanuCSE! what is the first 'df' on the right side of the equation?

Comment: @timyslava assuming df = dataframe1

Comment: got it. Thank you. I am still receiving 'c' values for some reason.

Comment: @DavidErikson, I am referencing the DFs above when I say I tried both of your solutions and I ended up with 3 values in one column because 'c' values were still in the DF.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation on @AtanCSE's solution, in case the number of original columns is large.  The difference is: provide list of columns to *drop*, versus list of columns to *keep*.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 
                   'B': ['a', 'b', 'a']})


mask = df['A'].isin(df['B'])
print('sum of mask is: ', sum(mask), end='\n\n')  # added for debugging
print(df.loc[mask, 'A'].to_frame())

sum of mask is:  2

   A
0  a
1  b
```

Comment: I appreciate your comment! I tested it out and am still left with 3 instead of 2 rows... I don't know where I am going wrong here.

Comment: I re-started Python and still get two entries.  I made a slight update (printed sum of mask, and removed `.to_frame()` -- neither affect number of rows.  What is your value of sum(mask)?